# The routes provided isn't triggered

Tags: magento, magento2

I just setup a new module, he is showing on `setup:upgrade`

But I get 404 when I try to get to my url.

The url I'm trying to match is : `http://website/acquisition`

This is my :

## etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Cpy_AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne" setup_version="0.0.2">
    </module>
</config>
```

This is my :

## etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="acquisition" frontName="acquisition">
            <module name="Cpy_AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

This is my :

## AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne/Controller/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Cpy\AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /** @var  Page */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context,
                                PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne Index.
     *
     * @return PageFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        var_dump('OK');
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is your namespacing. Magento will search for the `Index.php` in `AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne/Controller/Index`
Please try moving the Controller Class into a `Index` subdirectory of `/Controller` and changing the namespace accordingly.

Comment: Damn it was that simple :) Thanks